# Passing a js array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Why can't I access my array through $_POST in PHP? I'm trying to use the jQuery $.post method. Here is the corrected code with your suggestions:

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedValues;
var serializedValues;
$("td").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('selectedBox');

// map text of tds to selectedValues
selectedValues = $.map($("td.selectedBox"), function(obj) {
        return $(obj).text();

});

serializedValues = JSON.stringify(selectedValues);

// $.post('/url/to/page', {'someKeyName': variableName}); //exemple
$.post('handler.php', 
      {'serializedValues' : serializedValues}, 
      function(data) {
        //debug 
     }
);

});

</script>
```

My php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['serializedValues'])) {

            var_dump($_POST['serializedValues']);
            $originalValues = json_decode($_POST['serializedValues'], 1);
            print_r($originalValues);

        }


?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at what you're getting at the server using `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Would be nice to see the content of `serializedValues`

Comment: have tried var_dump($_POST), empty array, gonna work on this i guess

Comment: it is strange because i have performed some debug with alert() and each i click on the items i want, an array correctly generated with the correct value. @Dr.Molle, the content of serializedValues is just a serialization of the selectedValues, and it is generated properly too

Comment: Side note: most browsers have kind of developer tools panel. There you can inspect what is actually send when you make an AJAX request.

Comment: Also look into the [Tamper Data](http://goo.gl/1AES9) Firefox add-on for examining HTTP transactions.

Answer (score 4):

You should serialize your array into json string:

```
serializedValues = JSON.stringify(selectedValues)
```

And pass it to php. And then decode with json_decode:

```
$originalValues = json_decode($_POST['serializedValues'], 1);
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: thanks, i've read tons of stuff about json, but i was a bit afraid. I will try, seems like everyone love this now ^^

Comment: well, i've tried this. But the problem still remain the same, when i issue an isset($_POST['serializedValues']) in php, nothing is found.

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST['serializedValues']) say?

Comment: That means that your selectedValues varaible is null. What does console.log(selectedValues) say (you should get FireBug or Google Chorme to see, put it after selectedValues.push($(this).text());)?

Comment: Well, so i selected the second and fourth td, consoloe.log shows me :console.log(selectedValues)
[" 2 ", " 4 "]
undefined

Comment: When i do an alert(selectedValues) after the .each, it display the correct information too

Comment: And what does console.log(selectedValues) says?

Comment: Sorry. I mean serializedValues.

Comment: Oh ok. it returns me something like : a:1:{s:1:"0";s:3:" 4 ";} undefined

Comment: I don't know why there is the undefine word right after the output tho.

Comment: It's because console.log() returns nothing. Don't care about that. Can you give me a correct full (with all quotes) output of console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedValues))?

Comment: ReferenceError: selectedValues is not defined
arguments: Array[1]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "not_defined"
__proto__: Error

Comment: Well i figured out why it was strange, the output of console.log(selectedValues) was wrong from me. Big mistakes from me on the other version of the file, so it shows : ReferenceError: selectedValues is not defined

Comment: It's a scope problem, i need to declare selectedValues outside of the click() function. If I do that, console.log(selectedValues) output properly now, and console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedValues) output properly aswell

Comment: So what does console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedValues) output?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedValues))
[" 2 "," 4 "]

Comment: It's completly strange JSON.stringify() always returns string.

Comment: Oh god what the hell is going wrong with my code, im not going to write js anymore xD

Comment: Even if serializedValues is not a stringified well, $_POST should receive something in php right ?

Comment: there would be " 2 , 4 " in the $_POST yes, since [].toString is called as a minimum

Answer (score 2):

On a side note; your javascript could be refactored into something a bit more simple

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedBox');

    // map text of tds to selectedValues
    var selectedValues = $.map($("td.selectedBox"), function(obj) {
            return $(obj).text();
    });

    // $.post('/url/to/page', {'someKeyName': variableName}); //exemple
    $.post('handler.php', 
          {'serializedValues' : JSON.stringify(serializedValues)}, 
          function(data) {
            //debug 
         }
    );
});
```

Comment: i really like the way you select td, thanks for the lesson :)

Comment: ive tried it but seems like your map function doesn't push the values of td properly. when i alert(selectedValues), it just shows me ",".

Comment: ah, had to change $(this) by $(obj), pretty obvious

Comment: oh, sorry, edited that. also I removed the .filter(), since there's no benefit in using it in this case instead of a normal selector