# Passing js array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a js array to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071584/passing-a-js-array-to-php)

i'm stuck jQuery $.post() method, i can't access my through PHP $_POST and I can't figure out why.

Here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedValues;


$("td").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('selectedBox');

selectedValues = $.map($("td.selectedBox"), function(obj) {
        return $(obj).text();   
});

// $.post('/url/to/page', {'someKeyName': variableName}); //exemple
$.post('handler.php', 
      {'serializedValues' : JSON.stringify(selectedValues)}, 
      function(data) {
        //debug 
     }
);
});

</script>
```

And here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['serializedValues'])) {

        var_dump($_POST['serializedValues']);
        $originalValues = json_decode($_POST['serializedValues'], 1);
        print_r($originalValues);

    }
?>
```

When I issue a console.log(selectedValues) after selecting some of the td element, it return me this for exemple:

```
 [" 3 ", " 4 "]
```

Something else, when I inspect the sent header through XHR, i get this:

```
 serializedValues:[" 3 "," 4 "]
```

And finally, in php var_dump($_POST) still returns me nothing :(

Some hints ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Using an HTTP protocol analyzer, can you check the actual request that is issued to your web server?

Comment: You should update your previous iteration of this question.

Comment: I'm going to wireshark this then, sorry for the repost but i didn't get the response to the answer and I thought a fresh post woul be useful